# How to do 'all' and 'half ' instead of entering a given amount (economy)

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I have this code for a Discord bot command:

```
@client.command(aliases=['dep'])
async def deposit(ctx, amount = None):
    await open_account(ctx.author)
    user = ctx.author
    users = await get_bank_data()

    if amount == None:
        await ctx.send("Enter the amount you want to deposit")
        return

    bal = await update_bank(ctx.author)

    amount = int(amount)
    if amount>bal[0]:
        await ctx.send("You don't have that much money!")
        return
    if amount<100:
        await ctx.send("You cannot deposit less than 100!")
        return
  
    await update_bank(ctx.author, -1*amount)
    await update_bank(ctx.author, amount, "bank")

    await ctx.send("You have deposited {amount} to bank!")
```

How can I make it so that `all` and `half` can also be used for the `amount`?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Did you try writing code to check whether the value that was provided for `amount` is equal to one of those strings? (Hint: do you think this should happen **before**, or **after** trying to convert `amount` to an integer?) Supposing that the provided `amount` is, for example, equal to the string `'half'`, and given that you know the `ctx.author`'s current bank balance, can you think of a mathematical rule that tells you how much money to transfer? So, what if you try setting `amount` to that calculated value, in such a case, and then proceeding with the transfer?

Comment: All of which is to say: **what exactly is the difficulty here**? Please read [ask] and note well that this is **not a discussion forum**. It is your responsibility, before asking, to try to break problems down into logical steps, and **figure out where you are stuck and why**.

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of ways of doing this. Using your existing example - assuming `amount` is just a string then it's a relatively simple check.

```py
@client.command(aliases=['dep'])
async def deposit(ctx, amount = None):
    user = ctx.author
    await open_account(user)
    users = await get_bank_data()

    if amount is None:
        await ctx.send("Enter the amount you want to deposit")
        return

    bal = await update_bank(ctx.author)

    try:
        amount = int(amount)
    except ValueError:
        # will throw an error if amount is not castable to an int
        # check that it's equal to half or all
        if amount == "half":
            amount = (bal[0] / 2)
        elif amount == "all":
            amount = bal[0]
        else:
            # here, 'amount' isn't half/all and can't be converted to an int
            await ctx.send("Please enter a whole number or half/all")
            return

    if amount > bal[0]:
        await ctx.send("You don't have that much money!")
        return
    if amount < 100:
        await ctx.send("You cannot deposit less than 100!")
        return
  
    await update_bank(ctx.author, -1*amount)
    await update_bank(ctx.author, amount, "bank")

    await ctx.send("You have deposited {amount} to bank!")
```

You would just need to add to the command description that the user can enter 'half' or 'all' to deposit half/all.